# Search data in a list view using input from two textboxes

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am working with a basic banking system using VB.NET and MySQL and am having trouble with displaying specific data in the transaction history. The problem is, I want to display all transactions that occurred FROM a specific date TO a specific date (like a boundary or something). This is the line of code that I thought of using, but I can't get it to work:

Dim view As String = "select * from tblhistory where accountnumber = '" & txtAccount.Text & "' and date like '" & txtFrom.Text & "%' or date like '" & txtTo.Text & "'"

The concept that I had in mind was to, using the LIKE operator, make a user inputted boundary to display the only specific transactions that the user wants to see instead of displaying all the user's transactions and have trouble finding that specific transaction.

Can you guys help me figure this one out? Thank you very much. Good day. Here is the whole code by the way:

```
Public Class TransactionHistory
Public rights As String
Public log As String
Public accountnum As String
Private Sub btnProceed_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProceed.Click
    lvHistory.Items.Clear()
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server = localhost ; uid = root ; database = dbbank")
    Dim view As String = "select * from tblhistory where accountnumber = '" & txtAccount.Text & "' and date like '" & txtFrom.Text & "%' or date like '" & txtTo.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(view, con)

    con.Open()
    Dim data As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While data.Read()
        Dim entries As ListViewItem
        entries = lvHistory.Items.Add(data(0))
        With entries
            .SubItems.Add(data(1))
            .SubItems.Add(data(2))
            .SubItems.Add(data(3))
            .SubItems.Add(data(4))
        End With
    End While

    If rights = "manager" Then
        Manager.Show()
        Me.Close()
    ElseIf rights = "teller" Then
        Teller.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbType.SelectedIndexChanged
    lvHistory.Items.Clear()
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server = localhost ; uid = root ; database = dbbank")
    Dim view As String = "select * from tblhistory where accountnumber = '" & txtAccount.Text & "' and transactiontype = '" & cmbType.SelectedItem & "'"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(view, con)

    con.Open()
    Dim data As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While data.Read()
        Dim entries As ListViewItem
        entries = lvHistory.Items.Add(data(0))
        With entries
            .SubItems.Add(data(1))
            .SubItems.Add(data(2))
            .SubItems.Add(data(3))
            .SubItems.Add(data(4))
        End With
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub TransactionHistory_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtAccount.Text = accountnum
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: A banking system and you are not using sql parameters? Have you ever heard of [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: I have, I only copied the part where I am having problem with. I'll just copy the whole class to provide more information (hopefully)

Comment: Are you getting an error or just no result? I think you'd rather be using a 'Between' keyword to search for results where your date is between start and end values. And parameters. No bobby tables please.

Comment: I'm getting a result, but not the one I wanted--it only displays data from the one that I inputted in the txtFrom.Text and when I input something on the txtTo.Text, the items in the list view gets mixed up with data from another account numbers. Thanks for the answer my good friend.

Comment: I think you should be using a pair of DateTimePicker controls to capture the range from the user. Then your sql needs to change to use the 'Between' keyword in place of 'Like'.

Comment: But what if the user can't remember the time of the specific transaction and can only barely remember the date so he/she decided to input a range where she can find that particular transaction he/she is looking for?

Comment: The 'or' is causing your issue. It is effectively like asking for "everything for this account and a date like FROM" and also give me "everything with a date like TO". Adding brackets around your date conditions would resolve that.

Comment: Thank you my friend, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The 'or' is causing your issue. It is effectively like asking for "everything for this account and a date like FROM" and also give me "everything with a date like TO". Adding brackets around your date conditions would resolve that.

I think this would resolve some of the issue:

```
Dim view As String = "select * from tblhistory where accountnumber = '" 
& txtAccount.Text & "' and (date like '" & txtFrom.Text & "%' or date like '" & txtTo.Text & "')"
```

However, keep in mind that this will only look for transactions ON those specific dates, and not BETWEEN the dates.

Also try

```
Dim view As String = "select * from tblhistory where accountnumber = '" 
    & 
txtAccount.Text & "' and date between '" & txtFrom.Text & "' and '" & txtTo.Text & "'"
```

Lastly, use parameters.